# MPI distributing array

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to write a C++ program with MPI constructs. I want to read from a huge file and store the number into an array. I want the array to be local, i.e., I don't want all the threads to have the entire array because the array is very bulky. Each thread does local computation and "sends" and "receives" for further computation. What is the best way to do this? All the code I see online generate the local array using the rand() function, but I want to read the values from a file.

This is possibly want I want:

```
int main() 
{
    // Read from a file
    // store in array a[] temporarily
    //MPI_init();
    //My thread should have an array b[] that is a subset of a[]
    //MY code to do a numerical simulation
    //MPI_finalise();
    return 0;
}
```

PS: My data structure is more complicated than an array. I stores a huge graph. It's more like an array of linked lists or array of vectors.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To answer your question we need some more information from you. Please describe the format of the data you want to distribute. You should also explain the way in which this data should be distributed across the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

MPI is a message passing system between process not threads. It is a real difference when the process are running on different machines.

If the operation you want to do are complitely independant on each part of your graph I would go for a parrallel read. Other why if you want to have one read and spread an array you will have something like:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    MPI_init(&argc, &argv);
    int prank; MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &prank);
    int psize; MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &psize);
    if(prank == 0) {
       // Read from a file
       // store in array a[] temporarily

       MPI_Scatter(a, length(a)/psize, MPI_DATATYPE_OF_A, b, leanght(a)/psize, MPI_DATATYPE_OF_A, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
       // this works only if length(a) is a multiple of psize, otherwhy you should go for MPI_Scatterv
    } else {
       MPI_Scatter(NULL, 0, MPI_DATATYPE_OF_A, b, leanght(a)/psize, MPI_DATATYPE_OF_A, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    //My thread should have an array b[] that is a subset of a[]
    //MY code to do a numerical simulation

    MPI_finalise();
    return 0;
}
```

But this is the idea if you have arrays, if you have a graph you should give a look at a graph partitioner to split your graph and sent the pieces to the different procs. I think [Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov) does everything for you. Otherwhy you can just use [Scotch](http://www.labri.fr/perso/pelegrin/scotch/) or Metis to color your graph and then use MPI to send each color to a processor.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful. I plan to use par-Metis to partition the graph. I will also look into how that can send each part of the graph to the individual process.